# coverage probability vs. rejection rate

Tags: self-study

I am trying to calculate the coverage probability and rejection rates for confidence intervals based on the  ttest. I have the null hypothesis $H_0 = 0$ and $H_a \neq 0$

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between rejection rate and coverage probability here. Is the rejection rate equivalent to the number of confidence intervals that contain 0? I *KNOW* that my population has a mean of 0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Coverage rate has to do with the precision of your estimates and their error. Rejection probability has to do with the power of tests. For most tests, inference about the rejection of a hypothesis can be ascertained from whether or not the CI doesn't include 0. So high coverage probabilities tend to indicate undesirably  low rejection probability (aka power when the null hypothesis is false): this is called a conservative test. On the other hand, low coverage probabilities tend to indicate either a biased estimator or anticonservative error estimates, which can inflate or attenuate rejection probability.

If your pop has a mean 0, then I think you are saying the null hypothesis is true. In that case rejection probability is the false positive error rate. This roughly is also the probability that an experiment produces a CI which does not contain 0. So yes in this case that interpretation is correct.

Comment: So to understand correctly.... if I run a simulation and find that five percent of my confidence intervals contain 0, do I conclude that the rejection rate is 5%?

Comment: No, if you have a 95% confidence interval and you ran the simulation to infinity then the interval would cover it 95% of the time.  The actual rate will follow a binomial distribution.  You could get a very weird sample in repeated events enough to violate the 95%.  If you had a 95% interval and ran it 1000 times it would be unsurprising for it to test as a 94% or a 96% interval.  Confidence intervals are an asymptotic concept, for most problems.  It reflects a long run limiting probability and not a specific probability over any discrete set of samples.

Comment: @user119563 you have it backward. If the null hypothesis is $\theta=0$ and the null hypothesis is true, if 5% of your CIs contain 0 the rejection rate is 95% (i.e. you reject the null hypothesis every time the CI does *not* contain 0). That means the coverage probability is 5%. That also means you have a crappy test (95% type I error rate). If the null hypothesis is *false*, we can't say anything about the coverage (if the true mean is 2, but the CI is 0.4 to 1.6, then it does not cover the "truth"): but now your 95% reject rate at least tells you the test is sensitive: it is your power.